# Property 'target' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am making a search bar in Typescript but it is not taking any input. The term target on my onChange method keeps giving an error that

```
Property 'target' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

```
export default class userSearchPage extends Component <{}, { searchItem: string}>{
  constructor(props: Readonly<{}>) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchItem: ''
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (

  <div>
    <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
    <div className='main-content'>
      <SearchBar
        onChange={e => {
          this.setState({searchItem: e.target.value})
        }}             

        onRequestSearch={() => console.log('onRequestSearch')}
        style={{
          margin: '0 auto',
          maxWidth: 800
        }}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}
}
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: `onChange={e => {
          this.setState({searchItem: e.currentTarget.value})
        }}`

Comment: what is  this SearchBar?  can you show the code?

Comment: @Sodhisaab this gives an error ```Property 'currentTarget' does not exist on type 'string'.```

Comment: @eladBA I have already given the code. The search bar that I am using here is a material ui component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback `onChange` seems like it's already a string. So you can use it directly e.g.

```
onChange={e => this.setState({searchItem: e}) }
```

Comment: You mean like this ```onChange= {() => this.setState({searchItem: e})} ```or ```onChange= {this.setState({searchItem: e})}```None of them work tho

Comment: @x89 You need to only replace your `setState`... I edited the answer for you

Comment: Now it compiles without giving an error but my search bar is still not allowing me to type anything!

Comment: Because it is a controlled input. You need to set the `value` e.g. `value={this.state.searchItem}`

Answer (score 0):

I searched for your `SearchBar` material ui and in the documentation you can see that the `onChange` doesnt return the event but the actual value as you type. Which is a string...hence the error.

I would also suggest if you are using TypeScript to actually use types.

So for example your onChange should look like

`onChange={value: string => this.setState({searchItem: value}) }`